# proof that tangent line at point intersects function only at that point

Tags: calculus

How to prove that the tangent line at the point $(a,\dfrac{1}{a})$ on the function $f=\dfrac{1}{x}$ doesn't intersect $f$ at any other point.

Comment: A differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if the function lies above all of its tangents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- First, find the tangent line, $y=mx+c$.
- Try to find the solution to $mx+c = \frac1{x}$, the problem can be converted to a quadratic equation.